# My French keyboard layout is in QWERTY

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

Ubuntu now assigns a QWERTY layout to the "French" layout setting:

[image]

This occurred while I was trying to create a custom keyboard layout. Presumably I broke something while modifying the files `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fr` and `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml`. As far as I know, those files are now back to their initial state though. I'm at a loss as to how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Maybe try `sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data`? That should reinstall the package containing the xkb folder you mentioned...

Comment: @ByteCommander Great! I definitely consider that an answer to the question. I didn't know where to begin looking for how to reinstall those files. How did you go about finding the name of the package to reinstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you said you changed these files:

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fr
/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml
```

We can ask `dpkg` to which package these files belong, or also just their common folder `/usr/share/X11/xkb`:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/X11/xkb/
xkb-data: /usr/share/X11/xkb
```

So the package that contains these files is `xkb-data`. Reinstalling it should solve problems related to accidental changes:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data
```